# How to find the slope of a polynomial equation?

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-math

I'm currently using this code to find the polynomial equation and it's derivative for my data.
I'm using np.polyval to use the derivative and find the slope of each point on the curve.

```
    result = getDist(article_name, revilimit)
    xAxis = [i for i in range(1,len(result)+1)]
    xAxis = np.array(xAxis)  
    z = np.polyfit(xAxis, result, 10)
    p = np.poly1d(z)
    print('p = ')
    print(p)
    derivative = np.polyder(p)
    print('derivative = ', end='')
    print(np.polyder(p))
    #x = np.polyval(derivative, result)
    x = [(np.polyval(derivative,i)) for i in result]
```

[Here is the curve I got with degree 10 for the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivSjS.png) and 
[Here is the curve I got with degree 3 for the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRKZL.png)

The problem here is that I'm getting either all positive slopes(degree 10 curve) or all negative slopes(degree 3 curve) when I substitute the value of x in the derivative equation. 
Here is the equation of the curve and it's derivative that I'm getting,
[Degree 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4D3M.jpg)

All I want is to find the overall slope of the curve of the equation that fits my data.

Edit: As the comment below suggests I was entering Y axis value instead of X-axis value
Instead of

```
x = [(np.polyval(derivative,i)) for i in result]
```

I should have done this

```
x = [(np.polyval(derivative,i)) for i in xAxis]
```

Comment: Why are you plugging the y values instead of the x values into `polyval`?

Comment: I had something else in that place before and I must have overlooked it when I changed it. Guess it needed another pair of eyes. Thanks buddy and sorry for a simple question.